# Hex Edit with BinaryWriter (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

I'm opening an .exe file in Hex Workshop, and I want to edit **this** line:

[image: hex]

How is that possible with VB.NET using a BinaryWriter? The line represents the IP of the exe. I want to have a program that includes a textbox where you put the new IP. So, I have so far:

```
Using writer As BinaryWriter = New BinaryWriter(File.Open("C:\localhost.exe", FileMode.Open))
            writer.BaseStream.Position = ???
            writer.write???
            End Using
```

So, what position do I set it to, and what type do I write? Bytes? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx or at other codes like this: http://www.dotnetperls.com/binarywriter-vbnet What you are asking does not sound too difficult to be found out after a light reading about BinaryWriter.

Comment: Hard to interpret IP as anything else but Intellectual Property, usually covered by a license agreement that states that you cannot do this.  If you meant Instruction Pointer then do note that you are actually hacking *data* in that file, not code.  If you don't know where that data is located in the file then you don't have great odds of finding it back.  Other than with a tool.  Like a hex viewer.  Changing the file just takes FileStream, use Seek + Write.

Answer (score 0):

Find the offset of the first character in your string and use this method:

```
Private Sub Patch(ByVal TargetFile As String, ByVal FileOffset As Long, ByVal NewValue() As Byte)
    Try
        Dim br As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(File.Open(TargetFile, FileMode.Open))
        br.BaseStream.Position = FileOffset
        Dim byteB As Byte
        For Each byteB In NewValue
            If (byteB.ToString <> String.Empty) Then
                br.BaseStream.WriteByte(byteB)
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next byteB
        br.Close()
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub
```

Like this:

```
Patch("C:\localhost.exe", Val("OFFSET OF FIRST CHARACTER IN STRING"), New Byte() {&H31, &H32, &H37, &H2e, &H30, &H2e, &H30, &H2e, &H38})
```

Or instead of your byte-array, use this:

```
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("127.0.0.8") 'It'll change 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.8
```

Just make sure you have the right offset for the first character of your string